# Create Image Histogram Manually and Efficiently in Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

I want to write codes that can show the histogram of an image without using built in Matplotlib hist function.

Here is my codes:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def manHist(img):
   row, col = img.shape # img is a grayscale image
   y = np.zeros((256), np.uint64)
   for i in range(0,row):
      for j in range(0,col):
         y[img[i,j]] += 1
   x = np.arange(0,256)
   plt.bar(x,y,color="gray",align="center")
   plt.show()

def main():
   img = cv.imread("C:/Users/Kadek/Documents/MATLAB/2GS.jpg")
   manHist(img)

main()
```

My question is, is there a more efficent way to make an array of pixel value frequency without using for loop?

Comment: There's no other way than walking through every value in the image, though a vectorized numpy solution is going to be some orders of magnitude faster

Comment: So, you are not using the third axis of channels as you have : `y[img[i,j]]`?

Comment: You could use `collections.Counter` for this, although that might not be "manual" enough for you.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo thank you for your advice, but i don't understand how to use vectorized numpy.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, it's a grayscaled image.

Comment: Well then you should have `row, col = img.shape` instead.

Comment: @kindall Already tried that. It seems when there is no pixel with a specific value (example: 255), collections.Counter didn't write y[255] = 0. collections.Counter passing every 0 frequency, so the histogram is not in range [0..255], but only [0..254].

Comment: Writing a `Counter` subclass to return zero for missing values is pretty straightforward though.

Comment: why not numpy histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NumPy based vectorized solution would be with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
out = np.bincount(img.ravel(),minlength=256)
```

Another vectorized approach based on [`.sum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) -

```
out = (img.ravel() == np.arange(256)[:,None]).sum(1)
```

Sample run to verify results -

```
In [155]: # Input image (512x512) as array
     ...: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(512,512))
     ...: 
     ...: # Original code
     ...: row, col = img.shape
     ...: y = np.zeros((256), np.uint64)
     ...: for i in range(0,row):
     ...:     for j in range(0,col):
     ...:         y[img[i,j]] += 1
     ...:         

In [156]: out1 = np.bincount(img.ravel(),minlength=256)

In [157]: out2 = (img.ravel() == np.arange(256)[:,None]).sum(1)

In [158]: np.allclose(y,out1)
Out[158]: True

In [159]: np.allclose(y,out2)
Out[159]: True
```

Comment: both returning false in my codes. i wrote exactly same like yours.

Comment: @KadekDwiBudiUtama You haven't answered by question in the comments, whether that should be `row, col = img.shape` instead or not?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's work after using only 1 channel! Thank's!

Comment: @KadekDwiBudiUtama Kindly update your code in the question with that correction.

Comment: @KadekDwiBudiUtama Took the liberty to make the edit myself. If not coherent, feel free to make additional edits.